# Module vs. absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

Can I use a term "module" as an alternative for a term "absolute value"? For example, could this phrase be used:

> "We need to raise the module of the amplitude to the second degree"

for this expression:

> $p = |a|^2$

($a$ in this expression can be a real or complex number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term in English is [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value), the absolute value of a real or complex number.

[Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) is a generalization of vector spaces over rings.

In French, Italian, Spanish, and Portuguese, the same word (*module*, *modulo*, *módulo*) is used for both concepts.